# Symbolically solve for a variable, given multiple equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have two equations, let's say x=a+b and a=c, and I'd like to solve it for b.

I've tried this:

```
Solve[{x = a + b, a = c}, b]
```

But I get

```
Solve::naqs: b+c&&c is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.
```

Any suggestions how to correctly do this would be appreciated.

Comment: _is not a quantified system of equations_ That might have helped you find out that it should have been `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define equations use `==` !

```
Solve[{x == a + b, a == c}, {a, b}]
(*{{a -> c, b -> -c + x}}*)
```

Comment: Why {a,b}? Also the output seems to be {{}}.

Comment: You have two equations! Perhaps `Eliminate[{x == a + b, a == c}, {a}]` is what you're looking for?

Comment: That just results as 'true'. What I want as result is `b=x-c`

Comment: ok that works, had to clear all variables first. Looks like other open notebooks are somehow mixing the values together